# Rally: Pull stories counts by schedule state for a release?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to pull from the API of story counts for the latest release, broken down by schedule state. There's a report that does that currently, but I don't see any exposed method in the API. Does anyone know if that's possible to obtain?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do a query for each schedule state, and grab TotalResultCount from the body of the response.  For example:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=(ScheduleState = "Defined")

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=(ScheduleState = "In-Progress")
```

and so on.  Since there are only four "built-in" schedule states, plus an optional one before Defined and an optional one after Accepted, it's at most 6 requests.

Comment: Thanks Alan, though the totals don't match. The query from the Web service doesn't match the report results. The query I'm running is against Release.Name and ScheduleState. Is the query returning real-time results, or an archived total?

Answer (score 3):

You can further filter down Alan's examples above with some release information as well by changing the query parameter:

query=((ScheduleState = Defined) AND (Release.Name = "My Release"))

Are you writing an app using the App SDK or using one of our other REST toolkits (ruby, .net, python)?  You may be able to find some better code examples here:

http://developer.rallydev.com

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the Batch Query approach that allows you to just return the size of the query instead of counting the results.  See the 
"Getting the Size of a Collection" example of the api doc:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/batch.jsp#example8