# Counts on the server side via WSAPI?

Tags: rally

Is it possible to do object counts on the server side of Rally with the WSAPI?

For example, I've got an app that would like to count the number of unresolved defects for each project in our workspace.  I don't need to know anything about those defects themselves, so I just want a count, and don't need any other data pulled back.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out Alan's helpful answer to this Question:

[Rally: Pull stories counts by schedule state for a release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281708/rally-pull-stories-counts-by-schedule-state-for-a-release)

The analog for Defects would be:

```
     https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/defect.js?query=(State < "Fixed")
```

It does pull all the data, but you can grab the TotalResultCount attribute that is returned in the response to get the number of Defects matching your query.

Comment: If you also include pagesize=1 you'll get the minimal set of data back as well...  By default you'll get 20 results.

Comment: Yes, that should do it-- I do a regular query, only ask for one result, but tells me the number of items that matched my query via TotalResultCount