# Is there a way to get the defect count for a story?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I'm doing some queries using the new Rally Lookback API and am wondering what is the Lookback API analog to story counting REST request in traditional Rally webservices that is discussed in this question:

[Counts on the server side via WSAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537765/counts-on-the-server-side-via-wsapi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return all of the ObjectIDs of all of the defects for a particular story:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/1.27/<YourSubscriptionOID/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={_Type:"Defect",_ItemHierarchy:<OIDofStory>,__At:"current"}&fields=["ObjectID"]
```

If all you really want is the count, then add:

```
&pagesize=1
```

and pluck the TotalResultCount out of the top part of the result.

Comment: Just what I needed - this helps me get the same counts out of Lookback without having to loop on the results collection.